# Angular JS Form Values reset when toggling between two elements

Tags: angularjs

While switching back and forth with the radio buttons, the form values get reset. Why does `$scope.user` reset and does not stay persistent?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

app.controller(
  "myCtrl",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.radio_test = "0";
    $scope.user = "John Doe";
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
          <form>
            Choose:
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="radio_test" value="0">First</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="radio_test" value="1">Second</label>
          </form>

          <br />
          <div ng-switch="radio_test">
            <div ng-switch-when="0">
              <div>
                <form ng-app="myApp" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="user">Username:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" class="form-control" required />
                      <div style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
                        <div ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="1">
              <div>Something Else</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`controller as`**](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) syntax (*Run the below snippet in order to see how it fixes the issue*).

In your code you would need to change:

**1-** This

```
$scope.radio_test="0";
$scope.user="John Doe";
```

**to**

```
var vm = this;
vm.radio_test = "0";
vm.user = "John Doe";
```

**2**- This: `ng-controller="myCtrl"` **to** `ng-controller="myCtrl as vm"`

**3**- And every where you were accessing `anyVar` in the view (and in controller `$scope.anyVar`) **to** `vm.anyVar` (in the view and the controller).

---

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

app.controller(
  "myCtrl",
  function($scope) {  // there is no need to use the $scope any more
    var vm = this;
    vm.radio_test = "0";
    vm.user = "John Doe";
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm" class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div>
        <form>
          Choose:
          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="vm.radio_test" value="0">First</label>
          <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="vm.radio_test" value="1">Second</label>
        </form>

        <br />
        <div ng-switch="vm.radio_test">
          <div ng-switch-when="0">
            <div>
              <form ng-app="myApp" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="user">Username:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="vm.user" class="form-control" required />
                    <div style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
                      <div ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div ng-switch-when="1">
            <div>Something Else</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you this fixed my issue, I am not sure why though?

Comment: Whit this apporach the `user` var (for instance) is now bind to the controller scope (the controller as factory function) through the `vm` var and not to the (angularjs) `$scope` var which seems to throw away any varaible when is not being used. Then when in the view the var is created dynamically again it was finding the `$scope.user` as it was declared at first. I'm 100% sure about this flow but it seems to work like that. I'm not familiar with all the AngularJS internals, but I'm glad this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your ng-model on the input to `$parent.user` seems to do the trick.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

app.controller(
  "myCtrl",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.radio_test = "0";
    $scope.user = "John Doe";
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
          <form>
            Choose:
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="radio_test" value="0">First</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="radio_test" value="1">Second</label>
          </form>

          <br />
          <div ng-switch="radio_test">
            <div ng-switch-when="0">
              <div>
                <form ng-app="myApp" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="user">Username:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="$parent.user" class="form-control" required />
                      <div style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
                        <div ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="1">
              <div>Something Else</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```